# LinearLayout in Square Form

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

is it possible to have a LinearLayout inside a LinearLayout with equal height and width dynamically? i don't want to specify the values, just that the height is the same size of the possible width.

thx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have the same problem and i couldn't find a way to solve this using only xml. So i wrote custom layout and reference it from xml.

```
public class SquareLayout extends LinearLayout {

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
            // or you can use this if you want the square to use height as it basis
            // super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec); 
    }
}
```

and reference it in xml like this

```
<your.package.SqureLayout .....
</your.package.SquareLayout>
```

If there is easiest solution i'll be glad to know it.

Comment: Are there any cases in which this easiest solution will not work, and will require more complex solutions such as the answer by Alex North, or the Android implementation of [SquareFrameLayout] (http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/development/samples/browseable/ActivitySceneTransitionBasic/src/com.example.android.activityscenetransitionbasic/SquareFrameLayout.java) ?

Comment: @Mojo Risin, there is an easier solution now. Check out [SquareLayout](https://github.com/kaushikthedeveloper/SquareLayout) : [https://stackoverflow.com/a/46143213/7550472](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46143213/7550472)

Comment: And it also provides **auto adjustment** depending on which of the two dimensions (height/width) is **smaller**

Answer (score 2):

Expanding Mojo's answer a bit to handle either height or width being the constrained dimension according to context:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int size = Math.min(width, height);
    // Call super with adjusted spec
    super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(size, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(size, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
}
```

Comment: When is this required, and Mojo Risin's solution is not enough?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SquareLayout](https://github.com/kaushikthedeveloper/SquareLayout), an **Android Library** which provides a wrapper class for different Layouts, rendering them Squared dimensioned without losing any core functionalities.

The **dimensions are calculated just before the Layout is rendered**, hence there is no re-rendering or anything as such to adjust once the View is obtained.

To use the Library, add this to your build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.kaushikthedeveloper:squarelayout:0.0.3'
}
```

Your XML will look like :

```
<!-- Inner Linear Layout -->   
<com.kaushikthedeveloper.squarelayout.SquareLinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```