# Dynamically setting relative dimension of a linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to resize my LinearLayout (or a view) to a dimension which is relative to the parent or itself. For example, I want the width to be 1/3 of the parent's width. Or, the height should be same as its own width. I don't want to use any constants , so that it works for all devices.

adding code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_board"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout> 
        ...
</LinearLayout>
```

code:

```
public class GMActivity extends Activity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LinearLayout board_layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_board);
    // I wanted to resize board_layout here ..
    // getParent().getWidth() returns 0
    Log.d("gm", "layout: " + ((LinearLayout) board_layout.getParent()).getWidth());
    // ..
  }
}
```

getWidth() is giving 0. Is it too early to call this? If yes, what is the correct place to call this?

Basically my intention is to make the width of the layout a fraction of the screen size width, and, height same as its own width.

Answer (score 0):

Considering layout your LinearLayout and that its parent it's another LinearLayout:

Get the parent's width:

```
int parentWidth = ((LinearLayout) layout.getParent()).getWidth();
```

Get the view's width:

```
int viewWidth = ((LinearLayout) layout).getWidth();
```

set the

```
view.setHeight(viewWidth );
view.setWidth(parentWidth / 3);
```

Comment: Thank Nuno, for your answers. getWidth() is giving me 0. I am might be calling it at early place. Not sure where should I call it. I have edited my question to add codes for clarification.

Comment: what about the inner layout? does it return 0 as well? If that doesn't do it, instead of calling getParent, get the main layout's width using it's specific reference. since you know it's the main panel.

Answer (score 0):

I found height=width solution (square shaped layout) in [LinearLayout in Square Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803017/linearlayout-in-square-form)