# Is it possible to set my layout to be square and proportional to one of the two dimensions via XML?

Tags: android, layout

I don't think this can be done, but I'm going to ask just in case.

I have a situation where I want a WebView to be square. I need it to be 80% of the smaller of the two available dimensions and then for the other dimension to be the same length.

So, for example if the user is holding the device in portrait mode, I could set the parent  layout `weightSum` to 10, set the WebView's horizontal `layout_weight` to 8 and then have it automatically size the height to whatever the width winds up being.

I know how to do this at runtime in Java, I'm wondering if I'm possibly overlooking some fancy-schmancy XML technique that would accomplish the same effect.

It works nicely with Images (using `adjustViewBounds` and `scaleType`) but those params aren't visible to Layouts.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no trick to this per se. You could create a `SquareLayout` in Java, and use that in your XML, so you don't have to repeat the Java code everywhere. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5803095/115145

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be done in SDK XML.

You have to use code, but IMHO rather than doing it via setLayoutParams() at the fragment/activity level you should  subclass WebView (or it's container) and implement your special layout requirements in onMeasure().